# Comparing a string with an array

Tags: ruby

How do I compare `"string1"` with `["string1"]`? The following results in `false`:

```
params[:abc]         # => "neon green"
@abc                 # => ["neon green"]  
params[:abc] == @abc # => false
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. You are already successfully comparing them by `==`. What is wrong with it?

Comment: You cannot compare Array with String, the type is unconsistent here, you should precise what you want to do exactly.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `Array#include?`. However, this will return true if the array contains "string1" and "string2".

```
["string1"].include?("string1")            # => true
["string1", "string2"].include?("string1") # => true
```

In the event you want to compare the array contains only the string, I'd recommend using the `Array` method, which converts the parameters provided to it into an array.

```
Array(["string1"]) == Array("string1")            # => true
Array(["string1", "string2"]) == Array("string1") # => false
```

How it works:

```
Array(["string1"]) # => ["string1"]
Array("string1") # => ["string1"]
Array(nil) # => []
```

Answer (score 1):

you can wrap the second one in an array, or extract the string from the array

```
[params[:abc]] == @abc
```

or

```
params[:abc] == @abc.first
```

I kinda like the first one more

Comment: yea looks more elegant and neat. Thanks Mohammad!

Comment: No mohammad. this is not working.  [@abc]
=> [["neon green"]]  

[5] pry(#<AbcController>)> params[:abc].first
=> "n"

Comment: ah ok, i swapped the types, well you get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Another option - put the string inside an array of itself:

```
[params[:abc]] == @abc # => true
```

Or, if you don't know which one is an array, use an array-splat (`[*]`) combination:

```
[*params[:abc]] == [*@abc] # => true
```

Array-splat will work in a similar fashion to @Jkarayusuf's `Array()`:

```
[*["string1"]] # => ["string1"]
[*"string1"] # => ["string1"]
[*nil] # => []
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do:

```
@abc = @abc.join('')
#=> "neon green"

if params[:abc] == @abc
   do thing 1
else
   do thing 2
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
params[:abc].in? @abc
```

Comment: [`in?`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_many) is a _rails_ method, not a core-ruby method